# Ansible Host Variable

Tags: ansible

I have a very simple playbook that I run against hundreds of hosts by IP address.  These hosts are mobile devices and often change IP addresses.  When this occurs it can hang the entire playbook as it never completes the task. I added a local_action to wait for 30 seconds then continue.  The problem is that I can't figure out what the host variable is.  The IP address being passed from the host file does not show up in inventory as it is a cell connection.  What variable do I use to have it wait for the IP address I ran the playbook against?

```
---
- hosts: all   
  tasks:

  - name: Search Messages
    shell: /bin/grep 'eth1:'  /var/log/messages
    register: sysout

    - name: Wait For 30 Seconds
      local_action:
        module: wait_for
          host= "????"
          port=22
          delay=20
          timeout=30
      ignore_errors: true
      register: Back
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the current host using `inventory_hostname` variable:

```
- name: Wait For 30 Seconds
  local_action:
    module: wait_for
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    port: 22
    delay: 20
    timeout: 30
 ignore_errors: true
 register: Back
```

Comment: Yes,  This is the variable is was looking for.  Thank you.